# C++ std::pair<T,T> variadic template

Tags: c++, templates, std-pair, variadic

I've got a situation like this

```
template<typename T, unsigned int N, std::pair<T,T>... pairs>
struct Base{
    static constexpr std::pair<T,T> SOME_STATIC_ARRAY[N] = {pairs...};
};

struct Derived : Base<int,3,std::pair<int,int>(1,2),std::pair<int,int>(2,3),std::pair<int,int>(3,4)>{
    
};
```

I want to have something like this, but I get compile error

```
A non-type template parameter cannot have type 'std::pair<int, int>'
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: C++20 actually does allow this. g++ version 9 claims support of class non-type template parameters. clang does not yet claim support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A non-type template parameter can only be one of a [short list](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/134-template-non-type-parameters/) of types of objects:

- A value that has an integral type or enumeration
- A pointer or reference to a class object
- A pointer or reference to a function
- A pointer or reference to a class member function
- std::nullptr_t

Your temporary constructed instances of `std::pair` are not on that list.  Template parameters are very picky that way.  I don't remember the exact reason why they are so picky, but consider that template specialization involves asking "are these template arguments *the same*".  Equality of general objects is tricky (often involving an `operator==`), so drastically restricting the set of valid values to things which have trivial concepts of equality definitely makes compilers simpler.  Much to my chagrin, you can't even use *strings* as non-type template arguments, no matter how astonishingly useful that might be!

There are two solutions you can use to resolve this

- Instead of passing N pairs, pass N*2 individual integers, as integers are valid non-type template parameters
- Use `std::integral_constant` to pass in the integers, such as `std::pair<std::integral_constant<int, 1>, std::integral_constant<int, 2> >`.  This does *not* make a pair of integers, but it does make a *type* template parameter instead of a non-type template parameter.  You can then reconstruct the `std::pair<int, int>` whenever you like from templated functions.

  - as a potentially simpler variant, you could construct your own `template <typename T, T First, T Second> struct pair_integral_constant` class, which accepts two numbers of the same type.  It's the same idea: make this a type parameter rather than a non-type parameter.